# How did the girls' team manage to shut down Sora's driving skills?

Tags: ahiru-no-sora

In the starting episodes of *Ahiru no Sora*, it was shown that Sora had excellent drives and dribbling skills also along with shooting skills (when he played 5-on-1).

Now in these episodes, he is just a good shooter and does not show those skills at all. When they played Shinmaruko High, I can understand it was blocked due to his shooting from a side was weak.

However, when the boys played against the girls' team, how did the girls' team manage to shut his driving skills? It's a little awkward to me.

I have only watched till the anime has aired, so please hide the spoiler if it refers to future references.

Comment: A good answer contains the full detail, and sometimes spoiler is unavoidable. However, it's possible for the poster to hide the spoiler with `>!` markdown, and the reader is free to hover/click the spoiler block to read it or not.

Comment: Thankyou, could you also give me the link where they tell how to hide it?

Comment: It's on [the Markdown Editing help center/advanced help on the formatting toolbar](https://anime.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers)